# Options to obfuscate only URLs in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, obfuscation

What could be the all possible options to obfuscate my URLs in angular js.
For now I am trying base 64 encoding. 
e.g My URL is:

'URL': 'http://192.0.0.0/my/url/'

I encode it and decode it as well.

```
aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4wLjAuMC9teS91cmwv
```

Now in my code I am not able to embed it. May be I am doing wrong but how can i achieve this?

```
var a = $http.post('URL', data).then(function (response) { //Code }

                                          OR

 var a = $http.post('aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4wLjAuMC9teS91cmwv', data).then(function (response
```

Comment: I think the answer is straightforward, you have to decode your URL before calling `$http.post`

Comment: Yes but decoding will make it original like http://192.0.0.0/my/url/' . I do not want to display actual URL in code. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple javascript function that will do the decoding for you and just call that function instead of displaying the `URL` directly. Nobody will see the actual `URL` unless the user debugs the application.

```
<script>

var a = $http.post(decode('aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4wLjAuMC9teS91cmwv'), data).then(function (response) { //Code }

function decode(url) {
    var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/rn/g,"n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}
    return(Base64.decode(url));
}
</script>
```